# Missing .vue file in coverage report

Tags: javascript, testing, webpack, vue.js, nyc

I use vue-cli 3.0 to create my project, and I use `istanbul-instrumenter-loader` to create my coverage, but I can't find vue file

this is my vue.config.js

```
  chainWebpack: (config)=>{
    config.resolve.alias
      .set('@', resolve('src'))
      .end();
    config.module
      .rule("istanbul")
      .test(/\.(js|vue)$/)
      .enforce("post")
      .include.add("src")
      .end()
      .use("istanbul-instrumenter-loader")
      .loader("istanbul-instrumenter-loader")
      .options({ esModules: true })
      .end();
    // config
    //   .devtool("#eval")
    //   .end();
  },
```

this is my package.json

```
  "nyc": {
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.{js,vue,ts}"
    ],
    "extension": [
      ".js",
      ".vue",
      ".ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "dist",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "require": [
      "jsdom-global/register"
    ],
    "reporter": ["lcov", "text"],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "instrument": false
  }
```

[image]

[image]